# Server 2008 R2 and Server 2016 Power Options for hibernation when UPS battery critical

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016

We have a number of 2008 R2 and 2016 servers that are configured to hibernate when the UPS battery level is critical - Control Panel > System and Security > Power Options

Last night we had a four hour power outage, they all went into hibernation except one 2008 R2 box that just shut down...

The only difference I can see is that this one has an extra entry 'Change when the computer sleeps' - set to never - the others don't have this option. Could this have caused the problem, and if so how do I rectify it?

Thanks

Comment: TBH, why are you not shutting these down when this type of event occurs?

Comment: 1. There is a bug in server 2008 - that option doesn't work 2. There are a number of services (DB server as an example) that have to be started manually -